# Uniform cover of a uniform space

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ be a totally bounded uniform space with uniformity $\mathcal{U}$. For an entourage $E$ in $\mathcal{U}$, $\mathcal{F}=\{E[x] : x \in X\}$ is a covering of $X$. Is true that there is a uniform cover of $X$ which is a refinement of $\mathcal{F}$? Recall, a uniform space is totally bounded if every uniform cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: Is $\mathcal F$ itself already a uniform cover?

Comment: No $\mathcal{F}$ need not be a uniform cover.

Comment: I disagree: the $\mathcal{F}$ you wrote down (derived from $E$) **Is** a uniform cover by definition.

Comment: No, the cover $\mathcal{F}$ need not be an uniform cover. For if it is a uniform cover then it will have a finite subcover as the space is totally bounded. But this need not be true, for instance if the space is not compact.

Comment: It can be the case that this uniform cover has a finite subcover, while general open covers don't. Not every open cover is refined by a uniform cover !

Comment: Do you know an example of an open cover which is not refined by a uniform cover? If so can you kindly provide it here?

Comment: Define a uniformity $\mathcal U$ on a set $X=(0,1)$ by its base $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $U_n=\{(x,y)\in X: |x-y|<1/n\}$. It is easy to see that $\mathcal U$ is totally bounded. A cover $\{(2^{-n-1},2^{-n+1}):n\in\Bbb N\}$ of $X$ cannot be refined by a uniform cover.